# Load a custom attribute in the cart Magento

Tags: php, magento

Hi for a Magento website i need to load a custom attribute in the shopping cart.

i use getmodel function to load the items. but i have no clue how i load the attribute. maybe i haven't configure the attribute right. i have enabled yes for enable on product listing. de attribute code is 'staffel_percentage'. it is just a regular string

also when i change the price per product it doesn't change the subtotal maybe this is because we already change the price for the product on the rest of the website?

maybe it is in the event? i use this event: controller_action_layout_render_before.

this is the code in observer i use for it

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();                            // Gets the collection of checkout 
        foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {                                               // adds all items to $item and does the following code for each item

            if ($item->getParentItem()) {                                                       // If items is part of a parent
            $item = $item->getParentItem();                                                     // Get parentItem;
            }
            //echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';

            $percentage = 80;// init first percentage

            $quantity = $item->getQty(); //quantity

            //$staffelstring = loadattribute//loads attribute

            //gives the right percentage per quantity 
            //$staffelarray = explode(';', ^);
            //foreach($staffelarray as $staffels){
                //$stafel = explode(':', $staffels);
                //if($quantity >= $stafel[0]){
                    //$percentage = $Stafel[1];
                //}
            //}


            $currency = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyRate();                      // Currencyrate that is used currently
            $specialPrice = (($this->CalculatePrice($item) * $currency)* $percentage) / 100;                            //New prices we want to give the products

            if ($specialPrice > 0) {                                                            // Check if price isnt lower then 0
                $item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);                                           //Custom Price will have our new price
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);                                   //Original Custom price will have our new price, if there was a custom price before
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);                                      //set custom prices against the quote item
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the product right after your first if statement

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId()); // may be $item->getProductId() instead here
```

Then on the next line after that you can add some logging statements that will appear in var/log/system.log

```
Mage::log($product->getData()); // this will output all of the product data and attributes. You will see your custom attribute value here if it is set on this product.
```

If there is a value set for your product for your custom attribute then you can get it like this

```
$value = $product->getData('staffel_percentage');
```

As for the prices changing, not sure how you have the prices set up. You need to set a positive or negative number to add or subtract from the price in the fields found in the parent product configuration page in Catalog > Products > Your product > Associated Products.

See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYQeT.png) for what the section looks like.